# Mathematica equivalent of regex '\w{2,3}'

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

It beats me to write the Mathematica pattern equivalent to the regex:

```
\w{2,3}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, there is no point in writing it as a string pattern if you're happy with it as a regular expression. String patterns and regular expressions are completely equivalent and should be considered nothing more than variant syntactical forms.

Comment: I do not know what \w{2,3} is, but we have the `RegularExpression` function in *Mathematica* that handles all the usual regular expressions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's easy to search if you break it down:

```
Regex   Meaning             Mathematica command
-------------------------------------------------
\w      word character      WordCharacter
{2,3}   repeat 2 to 3 times Repeated[..., {2, 3}]
```

Combine it and use as:

```
StringMatchQ[{"a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"}, Repeated[WordCharacter, {2, 3}]]
(* {False, True, True, False} *)
```

However, you could just as well use the regular expression itself, which might be simpler if you're familiar with regexes:

```
StringMatchQ[{"a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"}, RegularExpression["\\w{2,3}"]]
```

The advantage of this is that it treats `_` as a word character, like most flavours of regex, whereas `WordCharacter` does not consider it valid.

```
StringMatchQ["a_", #] & /@ {Repeated[WordCharacter, {2, 3}], RegularExpression["\\w{2,3}"]}
(* {False, True } *)
```